# Privacy Policy change for different Countries / Continents on Website

Tags: gdpr, privacy, ccpa

I'm currently researching the GDPR Terms for a European Website. The Company has its headquarters and registration in Europe.

If someone from, let's say US, visits the website, do I have to cover the Rules and Terms of the American Privacy Policy?

Since the headquarters and registration is located in Europe, the legal Terms need to be covered in Europe.

Do you think we'll have to show different terms, considering from where the user enters the site?

Thanks for inputs!

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You must comply with the law everywhere you operate

So, yes. You must comply with American law (all 50 states pluses Federal), Samoan law, Thai law, Kenyan law, etc. to the extent that it applies to your operations.